# How to download generated pdf file when using window.print()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this JavaScript function to print a div content.

```
window.print();
```

At this time, Chrome generates a pdf file saved as

```
<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="chrome://print/32/0/print.pdf" stream-url="chrome://print/32/0/print.pdf" headers="" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="0" top-level-url="undefined">
```

how to can I download this file using JavaScript??

Any Help ?

Comment: press ctrl+p and save pdf format. it's best for other.

Comment: Currently I have a button for ctrl+p (printing), how can I get that pdf file automatically...

Comment: Try `window.location.href=document.getElementById('plugin').src;`